# sonata Admin current entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

How can i access the id of a sonata admin entity. suppose i have an entity EndPoint which have a function getProject(), how can i get the id of that project. I tried the code bellow but this gave me the following error: Attempted to call an undefined method named "getProject" of class "ContainerAgbGotv\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer".

```
class EndPointAdmin extends AbstractAdmin{
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{   $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $em = $container->getProject();
    
    $array = [];
    foreach ($em as $ems) {
        if (!empty($ems->getEnv())) {
            $array[$ems->getEnv()] = $ems->getEnv();
        }}
    $result = array_unique($array);
    $form
        
        ->add('name',ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'=> $result,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',

            'required' => false
        ])
        ->add('ipAdress',TextType::class)
        ->add('port',IntegerType::class)
               ;
}
```

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an admin you will have access to

`$this->getSubject()`

which will return you the current entity for that admin. It's worth noting configureFormFields is used for both creating and editing an entity so getSubject() may return null.

Comment: thanks for your reply but sometimes when i do this:  $em =$this->getSubject()->getProject()->getEnvironments(); i get the following error: Call to a member function getProject() on null

Comment: So you will need to do a null check on $this->getSubject()->getId() before calling getProject(). As configureFormFields is used for both editing and creating an entity, getSubject() will be null when creating for example

Comment: when i submit the form i get the following error "This form should not contain extra fields."  i couldn't fix it